# Set value on Interactive grid columns to another column

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an issue with IG if there any one can help me.
I upgraded to Oracle APEX 18.2, So I have to get rid of all Tabular forms and change it to Interactive Grids, the problem is that when I need to compute Net Value (QTY*UNIT_PRICE), I used to create a dynamic action like this:
`var row_id = $(this.triggeringElement).attr('id').substr(4);
$('#f11_'+row_id).val(parseInt($('#f04_'+row_id).val()) * parseFloat($('#f10_'+row_id).val()))`
Does anyone know how to do it in interactive grid?
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd now create a dynamic action; actually, two of them - on both QTY and UNIT_PRICE Interactive Grid's columns. Dynamic actions would look the same:

- event = "Change"
- true action: "Set value"
- set type: "PL/SQL Expression": `:QTY * :UNIT_PRICE`
- items to submit: QTY, UNIT_PRICE
- affected element: column NET_VALUE (or whatever its name is)

That should do it.

Comment: Yes, it worked fine, this is much easier than the old way

Comment: I have another issue, I'll open another question and I will happy if you can help me with it

Comment: Gives me a `ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here` error even if I make the affected result column Query only and use a function in the `select` for the column and the PLSQL expression.